# Sunspot rails, highlighted hit text is truncated, returning only one fragment containing the match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm implementing a full text search with sunspot, in which i store the text fields in order to get highlighted results.

Model code:

```
searchable do
    text    :name,         :stored   => true, :boost => 5.0
    text    :body,         :stored   => true, :boost => 3.0
    # ... some other non-text fields
end
```

controller code:

```
@search = Model.search do
    fulltext searchtext, highlight: true   # searchtext comes from params
    # ... some other fields
end
```

Rendering

```
@search.hits.each do |hit|
    hit.highlights(:name).each do |h|
        result = h.format { |word| "<result>#{word}</result>" }
        # output the result
    end
    hit.highlights(:body).each do |h|
        result = h.format { |word| "<result>#{word}</result>" }
        # output the result
    end
end
```

Everything works beautifully, except that when I am rendering the highlighted hit, I only get one fragment of the actual text.

So, instead of getting the phrase (which might be long), I only get a fragment of it. I've been trying around to put :fragment_size in the search definition (controller) but to no avail.

Any suggestion on how to output the FULL (:name or :body) and not just a fragment of it with highlight -> hit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, but even if it works fine, I believe there should be some other way, so I'm still expecting some answers, if you please.

My workaround goes as follows:

I remove the markups I placed in my highlighted hit into a new variable:

```
a=result.gsub(/<\/?result>/,"")
```

fetch the corresponding field with Active Record

```
model=Model.find(hit.primary_key)
```

and replace the unformatted text (variable `a`) with the formatted (variable `result`)

```
newresult=model.body.gsub(a,result)
```

thus resulting to the desired outcome.

Comment: Lacking answers, I accept my own cause it works. Any other answer that is better will get the "tick"